# Fetch Data from two tables mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in my database. "A" table is the main table that stores user primary information and other table "B" stores if user wants to add some additional address onto their profile.

Structure of both tables(**has common columns with exact same names**) is as per below picture except some diff columns that are not shown in this pic

[image]

Now i want to display Address stored in **Table A** as well as in **Table B**

I used below queries but all these return only values from **Table B**

**Query 1 :**

```
Select t1.(star),t2.(star) from `b` t2 , `a` t1 WHERE t1.emailbc = ?;
```

**Query 2 :**

```
Select t1.(star),t2.(star) from `a` t1 
INNER JOIN `b` t2 ON (a.emailbc=b.emailbc) 
WHERE t1.emailbc = ?
```

I also tried NATURAL Join but that does not work either. Please let me know solution.

Comment: use t1.(star) as star1 ,t2.(star) as star2

Comment: Can you show some sample data and how you want your results to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all addresses in one column, but coming from both tables, you need to use a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE emailbc = ?
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE emailbc = ?
```

Comment: @akr yes, but the way to OP explained it doesn't sound like a `JOIN` to me.

Comment: i think this served the purpose... but how about JOINS

Comment: `JOINS` will display the data adjacent to each other. If you want all addresses in one single column, you are looking for a `UNION`.

Comment: i do not want all address in single columns.. let me show you how i want addresses to be.. Here is the link to image... http://postimg.org/image/9in93jbd1/  .. i want all address to be displayed like this which i am getting with UNION.. but JOINS will be much beeter

Answer (score 0):

Change your join query to the following.

```
Select t1.*,t2.* from `a` t1 
INNER JOIN `b` t2 ON (t1.emailbc=t2.emailbc) 
WHERE t1.emailbc = ?
```

Comment: I can't spot the difference between your query and theirs?

Comment: @McAdam331, the query had not used the alias t1 and t2 in the on part of the query.

Comment: @akr .. this does not chnage anythng